What is the correct way to obtain a String from a Foreign Function that returns a char pointer
Is there an efficient way to obtain a Java string from a Foreign Function that returns a C-style char pointer?
For example the SQLite library contains a function to return the library version number:
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_libversion(void);

Using Java's Foreign Function and Memory API I can call this function like so:
final MemorySegment ms = this.symbolLookup.find("sqlite3_libversion")
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not find method 'sqlite3_libversion"));
final FunctionDescriptor fd = FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.ADDRESS);
final Linker linker = Linker.nativeLinker();
final MemorySegment result = (MemorySegment)linker.downcallHandle(ms, fd).invoke();
try (final Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined()){
    final MemorySegment ptr = result.reinterpret(10, arena, null);
    return ptr.getUtf8String(0);
}

The problem with this is that I have created a new MemorySegment of an arbitrary size 10. This is fine for this example but what is the correct way to obtain a String from a char * when I have no idea of the size of the char array?

The MemorySegment::getString(long) method (Java 22) is designed to read a null-terminated string. So, you can use reinterpret(Integer.MAX_VALUE).getString(0) to read any null-terminated string of arbitrary length that has a chance of fitting in a Java String. The reinterpret doesn't actually allocate any more memory, it just changes the bounds (on the Java side).

You can reinterpret to a smaller size if you want to be safer (e.g., in case of a function that is liable to return a string that isn't properly terminated). In that case, choose a size that is likely to be big enough for any reasonable string (where "reasonable" is determined by the context of the code).

("changes the bounds" would be more accurate as "returns a new instance with the new bounds")

@Slaw do you have a reference to where it states that reinterpret adjust only the bounds on the Java side?

The docs don't seem to make it explicit. But the overall documentation of MemorySegment and the general design of the FFM API does at least imply it. As pointed out by Jorn in another comment, a segment is essentially a pointer to a region of memory (see this Javadoc section). And allocating native memory from Java is the job of a SegmentAllocator.

@Slaw I'd agree the docs aren't explicit but upon reflection the name of the method(s) retinterpret() and re-reading the initial paragraph of MemorySegment docs does indicate that it's a wrapper which can as you say have it's boundaries altered but does not alter the native memory that backs it. Still it might be useful for a sentence in the docs to clarify this point. I believe it's still possible to go 'off the end' of an array if not careful but then this is no worse a case if using C alone.

"I believe it's still possible to go 'off the end' of an array if not careful but then this is no worse a case if using C alone" -- Yeah, one has to be careful using reinterpret. Those methods are explicitly unsafe; misusing them can lead to crashes or corrupted memory, hence them being "restricted". Though with getString, you should be fine as long as the string is null-terminated and the segment's size is at least the length of the string.

You should be able to re-interpret the MemorySegment to a size for the UTF-8 conversion, with suitable value for byteSize. Some APIs/libraries may have documentation or header file definition which gives you the expected size:
// JDK21:
return result.reinterpret(byteSize).getUtf8String(0);

// JDK22:
return result.reinterpret(byteSize).getString(0);

The reinterpret call does not re-allocate a chunk of memory with size byteSize - it just returns a MemorySegment that permits access to that range.
Example JDK22 which uses large size:
private static final SymbolLookup SQLITE = SymbolLookup.libraryLookup("sqlite3", Arena.global());
private static final MemorySegment MS = SQLITE.find("sqlite3_libversion")
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not find method 'sqlite3_libversion"));
private static final Linker LINKER = Linker.nativeLinker();
private static final MethodHandle MH = LINKER.downcallHandle(MS, FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.ADDRESS));

public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
    final MemorySegment result = (MemorySegment)MH.invoke();
    String ver = result.reinterpret(Integer.MAX_VALUE).getString(0);
    System.out.println("SQLITE version "+ver);
}

Note that using jextract simplifies setting up the bindings.

Isn't there a risk with using Integer.MAX_VALUE when reinterpreting the memory segment? The Javadoc appears to imply that whatever value is passed is the size of the new MemorySegment

@D-Dᴙum A MemorySegment can be thought of as a pointer to a memory region, with bounds (size, lifetime, thread) attached to it. reinterpret creates a new pointer that points at the same memory region, but with different bounds attached to it.

@Jorn That a segment's size is not directly linked to the underlying memory region could probably be more explicit in the documentation. Unless I'm missing something, I can see how someone might not find that immediately clear. Honestly, as good as the docs are (and I find them to be pretty good), some things can still be surprising. For instance, apparently the segment returned by reinterpret will always be writable, even if the originating segment was read-only. I see no indication of that in the docs; I'm not even sure if that's expected behavior or a bug.

@Slaw I feel like that is fairly obvious if you consider the the asSlice method. This also returns a new view of the underlying region with a different, smaller, size. Maybe we could add some words like ", backed by the same region of memory".

@Slaw The read-only issue with reinterpret is a bug. At the very least the javadoc should say if it alters the read-only property, but in this case reinterpret should not alter the read-only property at all.

@Jorn I think it's fairly obvious as well, but not necessarily immediately obvious. I wanted to answer this comment and was hoping for some specific sentence or paragraph that I could point to instead of relying on "Well, if you read the documentation in its entirety, you'll see that's how MemorySegment is designed".

@Slaw I agree. The information should be 'locally' available when looking at reinterpret (and asSlice). I've filed: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8333886 for clarifying the documentation, and https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8333884 for the bug you found.
